# Shell script works fine by itself, but produces unexpected results when run through git filter-branch

Tags: git, bash, shell, git-filter-branch

Here is the script that I want to run using `git filter-branch`:

```
#!/bin/bash
if test -e src/unlagged.cpp; then
    more +34 src/unlagged.cpp | cat ~/newlic.cpp.txt - > /tmp/unlagged.cpp
    cp /tmp/unlagged.cpp src/unlagged.cpp
fi
if test -e src/unlagged.h; then
    more +34 src/unlagged.h | cat ~/newlic.h.txt - > /tmp/unlagged.h
    cp /tmp/unlagged.h src/unlagged.h
fi
```

Pretty simple.  It takes everything past the first 34 lines of `src/unlagged.cpp` and `src/unlagged.h`, concatenates it with the contents of a text file, then writes it out to a temporary file, which is then copied on top of the file I wished to modify.  This works great as long as I'm simply running it inside my source tree, as the output of `src/unlagged.cpp` looks like:

```
(newlic.cpp.txt)
(everything passed line 34 of src/unlagged.cpp)
```

However, when I run `git filter-branch '/path/to/script.sh' -- --all`, the files are modified thusly...

```
(newlic.cpp.txt)
::::::::::::::
src/unlagged.cpp
::::::::::::::
(entire src/unlagged.cpp)
```

Where did those colons and the name of the file come from?  Why didn't it actually trim `src/unlagged.cpp`?  I tried the script with `#!/bin/sh` and got the same result.  I'm using git 1.7.7.3, by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `tail -n +34` instead of `more +34`.  You are being interfered with by the interactive nature of more.  As an example, run `more +34 src/unlagged.cpp < /dev/null` and you will see the :::::::::: lines.